# Receiving blank white square box while downloading image from amazon S3

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3, angular-promise

I was uploading the image to S3 from my api and downloading from the another front end application. I see a white square box instead of actual image I uploaded to S3.

**API Code**

after receiving response I am reading the file, I think there is a promise issue here, how to solve this issue. Promise is not being returned by the time function is being executed. I appreciate the help.

**done funtion**

```
      $scope.done = function {

        var s3Url;
        var allURLs = [];
        if($scope.files.length > 0){
    Service.methods.createUrl(getExtension($scope.files[0].name), $scope.files[0].type).then((response) => { 
        s3URL = response.data.signedUrl;
        allUrls.push(response.data.url);
        return;
   }).then(() => {
      return fileReader($scope.files[0]);
   }).then((data) => {
      return Service.methods.putDataInS3(s3URL, data, $scope.files[0].type);
   }).then(() => {
    return createMsg(allUrls);
   }).catch((error) => {
        $log.error('Could not upload attachment.', error);
        showError('Could not upload attachment.');
    });




function fileReader(file){
var promiseReader = $q.defer();
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

            reader.onload = function(){
                // var result = reader.result;
                promiseReader.resolve(reader.result);
            };

            reader.onError = function(){
                $log.error('Error reading file.', reader.error);
                promiseReader.reject(reader.error);
            };

            return promiseReader;
}
```

Comment: Please post all relevant code. From your snippet it doesn't make sense

Comment: @MaximShoustin sure..!